# I am using IB. For some reason, I have one XIB that when I open it I cannot see the layout view?

Tags: iphone

I am having a Interface Builder tool issue. I have a XIB that is not being displayed in layout mode (where I can see text fields I have added etc.) Doesn't happen with any other XIB. What is going on? I can't seem to find any command to make it show.

Tia.

Comment: Hi, could you explain your problem better? It's a bit confuse what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

Is your problem that you just can't see the layout of your text fields, buttons etc. for the view of the *.xib?  If so then try double-clicking the 'View' rectangle in the window next to 'File's Owner' and 'First Responder'?  This will make the 'View' window open, showing the layout of all your GUI components as you arranged them before.

Answer (score 0):

Reveal In Workspace from the Tools menu in IB allowed me to see the view such that I could edit it.